# Landsat images from same path/row have different shapes

Tags: python, landsat, rasterio

I'm starting to play with satellite imagery. In particular, I am using images of the Landsat 7 and Python. I open two TIF images of the same place but at different times to the `numpy` arrays and they have different shapes.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio

with rasterio.open(image1_path) as src:
    B1_t1 = src.read().astype(read_astype)[0]
with rasterio.open(image2_path) as src:
    B1_t2 = src.read().astype(read_astype)[0]

B1_t1.shape
B1_t2.shape

#OutPut
#>>>(7811, 6951)
#>>>(7791, 6941)
```

These two images are from the same path/row.

Comment: Have you actually tried viewing these images in a GIS? Are they shifted in some way, got NODATA columns. That's the first place I would start to try and identify why they are different. For example if they are identical when viewed in a GIS it would suggest the mechanism you are using now is corrupted in some way?

Comment: Yes, they do. You can count on rasterio (and GDAL, under the hood) to read TIFFs properly.